# Form a "chain" of relationship through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say I have a database where I want to model a many-to-many relationship between users and the websites they have access to.

I have the tables `users` and `websites`, and I create a third `users_have_sites` table with two foreign keys to modelize this many-to-many relationship.

With SQLAlchemy, this looks something like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Foreignkey

Base = DeclarativeBase()

class User(Base):
     __table_name__ = "users"
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     link = relationship("UserHasWebsite", back_populates="user")
     ... # Other columns
     
class Website(Base):
    ___table_name__ = "websites"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = relationship("UserHasWebsite", back_populates="website")
    ...

class UserHasWebsite(Base):
    __table_name__ = "users_have_websites"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="link" )
    website = relationship("Website", back_populates="link")
```

I can get a list of `Website` instances linked to an user by calling `[link.website for website in user.link]`, but I was wondering if there was the possibility to pass this "chained" relationship in the definition of the class, so that I could directly call an attribute `user.websites`

Comment: Please read the [Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) page of the documentation, where you will find `User-Keyword` many-to-many example with various ways it could be done depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `association_proxy` (it's also possible to use an association proxy on top of another association proxy if needed):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Foreignkey
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

Base = DeclarativeBase()

class User(Base):
     __table_name__ = "users"
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     link = relationship("UserHasWebsite", back_populates="user")
     website = association_proxy("link", "website")
     ...
     
class Website(Base):
    ___table_name__ = "websites"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = relationship("UserHasWebsite", back_populates="website")
    user = association_proxy("link", "user")
    ...

class UserHasWebsite(Base):
    __table_name__ = "users_have_websites"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="link" )
    website = relationship("Website", back_populates="link")
```

But you might want to consider an association table instead if you *only* need the relationships from `UserHasWebsite` and no other columns:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Foreignkey

Base = DeclarativeBase()

UserHasWebsite = Table(
    "users_have_websites", Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('website_id', Integer, ForeignKey('websites.id'), primary_key=True),
)

class User(Base):
     __table_name__ = "users"
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     website = relationship("Website", secondary=UserHasWebsite, back_populates="user")
     ...
     
class Website(Base):
    ___table_name__ = "websites"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = relationship("User", secondary=UserHasWebsite, back_populates="website")
    ...
```